# Laravel - pagination with created_at pages sorting

Tags: laravel, pagination

So guys I'm working on this project and I need laravel pagination. I already tried laravel basic pagination with `$posts->links()` on my blade but it is not working. I think like there is some update on it or something. I need pagination to be paginate by created_at, so on one page it needs to show me all posts created at same day. Can you pls help me

Here is my HomeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Post;
use DB;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find($user_id);
        return view('home')->with('posts', $user->posts);
    }


}
```

Here is my home.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.theme')

@section('content')
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #EBEBEB;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="mainl">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="columna">



                <h1>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</h1>
                <hr>
            </div>

            <div class="columns">
                <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" id="logout"
                onclick="event.preventDefault();
                        document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                    {{ __('LOGOUT') }}
                </a>

                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                    @csrf
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
        </br></br></br>

        @if(count($posts)> 0)
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>BR.KESICE</th>
                    <th>IME I PREZIME</th>
                    <th>BR.TELEFONA</th>
                    <th>POSAO</th>
                    <th>CIJENA</th>
                    <th>PLACANJE</th>
                    <th>POPUST</th>
                    <th>DATUM PREUZ.</th>
                    <th>DATUM IZDAV.</th>
                    <th>SMJENA</th>
                    <th>RADNIK</th>
                    <th>STATUS</th>
                    <th>IZMIJENI</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($posts as $post)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$post->br_kesice}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->ime}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->br_telefona}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->posao}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->cijena}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->placanje}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->popust}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->datum_preuz}}</td>
                    @if($post->status == 1)
                        <td>/</td>
                    @else
                        <td>{{$post->datum_izdav}}</td>
                    @endif
                    <td>{{$post->smjena}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->radnik}}</td>
                    <td>
                        @if($post->status == 0)
                        <span class="label label-primary" id="statusdeaktivan">Deaktivan</span>
                        @elseif($post->status == 1)
                        <span class="label label-success" id="statusaktivan">Aktivan</span>
                        @elseif($post->status == 2)
                        <span class="label label-danger" id="statusdeaktivan">Rejected</span>
                        @else
                        <span class="label label-info" id="statusdeaktivan">Deaktivan</span>
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    @if($post->status == 3)

                    @else
                    <td><a href="posts/{{$post->id}}/edit" class="edit"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></a></td>
                    @endif

                </tr>

                @endforeach
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>UKUPAN IZNOS:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                    <th>KARTICA:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts->where('placanje', 'Kartica')->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                    <th>GOTOVINA:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts->where('placanje', 'Gotovina')->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                    <th>VIRMAN:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts->where('placanje', 'Virman')->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>

        @else
            <p>Trenutno nema unosa.</p>
        @endif
    </div>
@endsection
```

if you need anything else to help, please comment and I will add it.

Comment: *I need pagination to be paginate by created_at, so on one page it needs to show me all posts created at same day.* - so you want to **paginate** or **show records belongs to certain day on one page**? These two goals are different, because in the case of pagination you could have records with different `created_at` days on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you're not getting your `posts` paginated, but all of them.

You just need to change `$user->posts` to `$user->posts()->paginate()` for it to work. Optionally, you may pass a number to the paginate method to tell it how many records per page do you need.

Hope it helps!

Comment: So if I understand you, I need to do this:
```public function index()
    {
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find($user_id);
        return view('home')->with('posts', $user->posts->paginate());
    }```
in my HomeController, and to add ```$posts->links()``` in my home.blade.php?

Comment: I did it but it returns me Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.

Comment: No, call the posts as `$user->posts()->paginate()`. By calling the relation with `()` you access the relations model methods, whereas by just calling it like `$user->posts` would return you the Eloquent collection of the items. Think of `$user->posts()` as an instance of `\App\Post`.